# How to simplify my elif code in python

Tags: python

I am viswa. I prepared a simple code using elif command.
I will share the code and condition... it is working. but I am looking for simplified program. if anything available for the same result

inputs names are= 'AEX_ABC','AEX_XXX','AEX_YYY','CAI_XXX','CAI_YYY'....etc.,
output should be AEX_1,AEX_2,AEX_3,CAI_1,CAI_2,....

program:

```
        name=(<user input>)
        AEX,CAI,CAR,CCA,CEL,CLM,CRE,ECH,FAV,FRE,GMP,INS,ROU,TAR,TAV,UAV,VEH,ERROR=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        name=part._name.split('_')
        if name[0]=='AEX':
            AEX+=1
            i=AEX
        elif name[0]=='CAI':
            CAI+=1
            i=CAI
        elif name[0]=='CAR':
            CAR+=1
            i=CAR
        elif name[0]=='CCA':
            CAR+=1
            i=CCA
        elif name[0]=='CEL':
            CEL+=1
            i=CEL
        elif name[0]=='CLM':
            CLM+=1
            i=CLM
        elif name[0]=='CRE':
            CRE+=1
            i=CRE
        elif name[0]=='ECH':
            ECH+=1
            i=ECH
        elif name[0]=='FAV':
            FAV+=1
            i=FAV
        elif name[0]=='FRE':
            FRE+=1
            i=FRE
        elif name[0]=='GMP':
            GMP+=1
            i=GMP
        elif name[0]=='INS':
            INS+=1
            i=INS
        elif name[0]=='ROU':
            ROU+=1
            i=ROU
        elif name[0]=='TAR':
            TAR+=1
            i=TAR
        elif name[0]=='TAV':
            TAV+=1
            i=TAV
        elif name[0]=='UAV':
            UAV+=1
            i=UAV
        elif name[0]=='VEH':
            VEH+=1
            i=VEH
        else:
            ERROR+=1
            i='error'+str(ERROR)
        output=name[0]+i
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace this with a dictionary lookup.

```
stock_indices={<all stock indices:0>}
error=0
try:
    stock_indices[input[0]]+=1
except KeyError:
     error+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jesse Bakker says, this is a job for a dictionary. Whenever you find yourself creating a whole bunch of variable names to track a group of related items you should probably be using a dictionary instead. You *can* use a `dict` literal to initialize the dictionary, but when all of the items have the same initial value it's convenient to use the `dict.fromkeys` class method, as shown below.

To keep the code lines short I've split the `keys` string into two strings: Python will automatically join adjacent string literals, but we need to wrap the expression with parentheses so that the parser knows that it continues over more than one line.

```
keys = ('AEX,CAI,CAR,CCA,CEL,CLM,CRE,ECH,FAV,FRE,'
    'GMP,INS,ROU,TAR,TAV,UAV,VEH,ERROR'.split(','))

stock_indices = dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)

def update_stock(name):
    key = name.partition('_')[0]
    if key not in stock_indices:
        key = 'ERROR'
    val = stock_indices[key] + 1
    stock_indices[key] = val
    return key, val

# Test
test = (
    'AEX_ABC', 
    'AEX_XXX', 
    'AEX_YYY', 
    'BAD_ZZZ',
    'CAI_XXX', 
    'CAI_YYY', 
)

for name in test:
    key, val = update_stock(name)
    print('{0}_{1}'.format(key, val))
```

**output**

```
AEX_1
AEX_2
AEX_3
ERROR_1
CAI_1
CAI_2
```